# Inc/dec mongotemplate, atomically

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update one value of my document atomically using `findAndModify`, which according to my reading is atomic in the same document. According to my Unit test the values are not modified.

I'm using mongoTemplate in Java, and my code looks like

```
    public OfferConfiguration IncreaseStock(OfferConfiguration offerConfiguration) {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(offerConfiguration.getId()));
        Update update = new Update().inc("stock", 1);
        return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, OfferConfiguration.class);
    }

    public OfferConfiguration findAndDecreaseStock(String offerId ) {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(offerId).and("stock").gt(0));
        Update update = new Update().inc("stock", -1);
        return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, OfferConfiguration.class);
    }
```

Stock has type Long, and I can see that when I use a criteria in the find:

```
  Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(offerId).and("stock").gt(0));
  return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, OfferConfiguration.class);
```

It returns only the values whose stock is greater than 0.

Any idea what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Do you want it to query all values, not just those that are greater than 0? If so then I think you should remove the `.gt(0)`

Comment: No I just want decrease the stock if is not already 0, that´s why I add that criteria in my query. And I dont know how to decrease values using Update(), in any case IncreaseStock and findAndDecreaseStock are not working, and I need to know why

Comment: I found the issue myself, I had to add  new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true) into the findAndModify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FindAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) will return the original document after making the update to it by default.

If you want to get back the modified document you have to pass it the optional *new* option.
It seems you already found that the way to do that is by adding `returnNew(true)` to the `findAndModify` command.